# Eclipse Plug-in use standard Format function in the code

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a plugin for Eclipse and I created a StructuredTextEditor. The editor contains an XML. And I want to align the code nicely (like indent etc.). I search a possibility to apply the standard function "Format" of Eclipse <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.
I found a code snippet that does exaclty this but I didn't get it to work:

```
    String commandId = IJavaEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT;
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I always get the following Exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.NotHandledException: There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.format
```

Does anyone can help me get running this code, or got en other solution to **format the xml content**, its important to use the same format like the eclipse formatter uses.

Comment: The formatting command, if there is one, would be different for XML. Formatting doesn't exist for every editor, so they would all be different.

Comment: The id `IJavaEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT` is for the Eclipse JDT Java editor code formatter. The JDT Java editor is the only editor that will respond to this.

Comment: Hm but why the SHIFT+CTRL+F is working in my StructuredTextEditor() ? Is this not calling exactly the same as IJavaEditorActionDefinitionsIds.FORMAT?

Comment: No it is not calling the same thing. Shft+Ctrl+F is bound to different commands depending on the active context, the Java editor has it own context.

Comment: And do you know where i can find the bound function in case of the StructuredTextEditor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to greg-449 I searched the correct function to call and found it.
Here is my function that works with StructuredTextEditor.

```
private void formatString() {
    String commandId = "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.format.document";
    IHandlerService handlerService = (IHandlerService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);
    try {
        handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    }
}
```